# Javascript : What does contentType: !1 means?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, content-type

I have seen in multiple cases where the   `contentType`,    `cache`    etc are mentioned as `!1`. Haven't seen much documentation for the same. Can someone tell me what that means?

```
$.ajax({
                 url: url,
                 data: FormData1,
                 cache: !1,
                 contentType: !1,
                 processData: !1,
                 type: 'POST',
                 beforeSend: function() {},
                 complete: function(responseData){
    
                }
              });
```

Comment: there is not much to add `!1 === false`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski What will be request contentType in that case?

Comment: from documentation ` As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content type header.`

Comment: I see. Thank you @KrzysztofKrzeszewski

Answer (score -1):

contentType is the type of data you're sending, so application/json; charset=utf-8 is a common one, as is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, which is the default.

dataType is what you're expecting back from the server: json, html, text, etc. jQuery will use this to figure out how to populate the success function's parameter.